# JS code is not working on the custom pages generated by plugin infinite-scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, infinite-scroll

Using [Paul Irish](http://www.paulirish.com/)'s jQuery Plugin:[infinite-scroll](http://www.infinite-scroll.com/). The problem is the JS functions which are registered on the custom pages generated by the [infinite-scroll](http://www.infinite-scroll.com/) are not working. Even though they are registered inside the Document.ready function inside the custom pages.

Any idea what causes this? And How it will be fixed.

Thanks.

Comment: I think we gonna need more info on this. What did console say? How did you debug your code? What problems did you find?

Comment: Based on the information provided I can conclude that you're doing something wrong. In Firefox (with firebug plugin installed) or Chrome you can press F12 and see the console. Check out if there are any errors. If not then you can put some `console.log` statements in your code to see if it is doing what you think it does. If that doesn't help you out then you can set a breakpoint (script tab in firefox or sources in Chrome) from there you can step through your script and see what it does.